# How to make dummy columns only on variables witch appropriate number of categories and suffisant share category in column?

Tags: python, pandas, categories, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below (both types of columns: numeric and object):

data types:

- COL1 - numeric
- COL2 - object
- COL3 - object

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | ... | COLn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | Y | ... | ... |
| 222 | A | Y | ... | ... |
| 333 | B | Z | ... | ... |
| 444 | C | Z | ... | ... |
| 555 | D | P | ... | ... |

And i need to make dummy coding (`pandas.get_dummies()`) only on categorical variables which has:

1. max 3 categories in variable
2. The minimum percentage of the category's share of the variable is 0.4

So, for example:

1. COL2 does not meetr requirement nr. 1 (has 4 different categories: A, B, C, D), so remove it
2. In COL3 category "P" does not meet requirements nr.2 (share is 1/5 = 0.2), so use only categories "Y" and "Z" to dummy coding

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
COL1 | COL3_Y | COL3_Z | ...  | COLn
-----|--------|--------|------|------
111  | 1      | 0      | ...  | ...
222  | 1      | 0      | ...  | ...
333  | 0      | 1      | ...  | ...
444  | 0      | 1      | ...  | ...
555  | 0      | 0      | ...  | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "COL1": [111, 222, 333, 444, 555],
        "COL2": ["A", "A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "COL3": ["Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "P"],
        "COL4": ["U", "U", "W", "V", "V"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Save first column in a new dataframe for later use
new_df = df["COL1"]

# Get number of unique values in each columns
s = df.nunique() # COL1 5, COL2 4, COL3 3, COL4 3

# Filter out rows with too many categories
tmp = df.loc[:, s[s <= 3].index]

# Filter out values with insuffisant percentage
# Get dummies and concat new columns
for col in tmp.columns:
    frq = tmp[col].value_counts() / tmp.shape[0]
    other_tmp = tmp[col]
    other_tmp = other_tmp[
        other_tmp.isin(frq[frq >= 0.4].index.get_level_values(0).tolist())
    ]
    other_tmp = pd.get_dummies(other_tmp)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, other_tmp], axis=1)

# Cleanup
new_df = new_df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
   COL1  Y  Z  U  V
0   111  1  0  1  0
1   222  1  0  1  0
2   333  0  1  0  0
3   444  0  1  0  1
4   555  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Laurent, what is "Setup" at the beginning of code? Why you do that: new_df = df["COL1"] and s = df.nunique() ?

Comment: Hi, I've removed "setup", it was just a way to indicate some initial statements. See my updated answer for additional comments. Cheers.